# Magento2: How to add cart summery(tax,discount,shipping etc) in minicart popup

Tags: magento2.3, mini-cart, popup, checkout-summary

***I want to display Shopping cart summery in mini-cart popup Like below screenshot can anyone help me out to display cart summery in minicart.***

[image]